# AWS Load Balancer security group between ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have set up an AWS Elastic Load Balancer and AutoScaling Group of 30 instances.

So under `AutoScaling Group` and `Load Balancer` I have 30 instances `InService`. And each instance is running a proxy server to receive http requests.

What if I want to run another program in a separate instance that is not one of those `30 instances`?

If I want to send `http` request through the Load Balancer, do I have to run the program only under the 30 instances associated with the `AutoScaling` group and `Load Balancer`? I am trying to run a program that sends `http request` through the load balancer in a separate `ec2` that is not associated with the load balancer but send through the `load balancer`'s `dns` . But this is hanging forever and eventually timed out.

Please help me~! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add instances that are not in an AutoScaling group to the load balancer, but you need to register it separately, while the group register the instances automatically.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean `register` the instance that I want to run my program with, to the load balancer?

Comment: Yes. You can have individual instances and more than one AutoScaling group registered to the same load balancer. There are lots of use cases for those in DevOps. Single instances are very useful for Canary Deployments, multiple AutoScaling groups for Blue/Green, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Requests coming into the **Elastic Load Balancer** will be sent to one of the Amazon EC2 instances registered with the Load Balancer (showing as InService). The instance will then respond to the request, with the traffic exiting the Load Balancer (the reverse of the way it came in).

If you wish to run another program in an instance that is separate to your Auto Scaling group, you cannot send requests to that instance via the Elastic Load Balancer, since the request will not reach your separate instance.

If you are intending to send a message "through" a Load Balancer, this is only possible if an instance is responding to a message that originally came "in" via the Load Balancer. You cannot send a new message "out" of a Load Balancer.